# Phoenix Presence: iterate through connected users in response to an event?

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

Suppose I have a Phoenix app that includes a realtime dashboard of data.

I have a channel called `MyApp.DashboardChannel`, with a single topic of `dashboard`.

In `MyApp.DashboardChannel`, I have a function like:

```elixir
def send_update do
  MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast(
    "dashboard",
    "update",
    %{data: MyApp.get_dashboard_data}
  )
end
```

Whenever something happens to modify the data being displayed in the dashboard, I can call this function to push out an updated version. For instance, in `MyApp.TransactionController.create`, after a transaction is saved, I can call `DashboardChannel.send_update` so that everyone will see the new transaction.

Now, suppose I want to modify this so that **each dashboard user gets customized data**. Essentially I want to say this: "for each connected user, run a query using their `user_id` and push the resulting data to them."

How can I do this?

I'm pretty sure the answer will involve `Phoenix.Presence`. I've already added it [as the docs show](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Presence.html#list/2), and am successfully getting `presence_state` and `presence_diff` events in the browser.

However:

- I can't use `Presence.list(socket)` when calling `send_update`, because I'm calling it from a controller which has no access to a `socket`
- When I call `Presence.list(MyApp.DashboardChannel, "dashboard")` I get an `** (EXIT) no process` from `GenServer`. Am I misunderstanding how to use this?

Comment: I suppose I could broadcast a message that says "ask for an update!" and let each browser do an HTTP request specifying its user's id. But that's super hacky.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to broadcast different data to each connected socket on a channel, the best way I know to do it is to drop down to `PubSub`:

```elixir
Phoenix.PubSub.broadcast(
  MyApp.PubSub,
  # Could be any channel ID
  "dashboard",
  # Could be an atom or a tuple with some data attached,
  # of the sort you would pass to a GenServer's `handle_info/2`
  :update
)
```

Then, in your channel module, you'll need a new `handle_info/2` callback to handle that event. Something like:

```elixir
def handle_info(:update, socket) do
  payload = make_update_payload(socket.assigns.user_id)
  push(socket, "update", payload)
end
```

Since this is using [`Phoenix.Channel.push/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.6.11/Phoenix.Channel.html#push/3) rather than, say, [`broadcast/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.6.11/Phoenix.Channel.html#broadcast/3), each connected user will get their own, personalized payload.